# Node JS push mySQL query to frontend for display

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Here's what I need to do,

- Query my database and get back a JSON array of items. Got it
- Parse the JSON list. Easy.

The part I get stuck on now is displaying this content on the HTML side. If it helps I am using express.js and node.js. The html content has a button in a form that posts to the node.js backend and queries the data. The issue is now sending that content back in a displayable format. I have seen some people using response.send() to push that data back to the front end, but I do not believe that is applicable in this situation because it simply overwrites my webpage.

```
        <form method="post" action="/loadInventory">
        <fieldset>
            <button type="submit" id="refresh">Refresh Inventory</button>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Then on the backend, it looks like this.

```
app.post('/loadInventory', function(req,response)
{   
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        //connection code
    });
  
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM inventory', function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err
        Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key){
            const row = result[key];
            //one individual result, push to array, then push array to table on front-end. 
        })
    })
});
```

I cannot use document.getelementbyid(#idoftable), not in node.js, and I tried using node local-storage and accessing that from front-end script attribute, but I can not do that because node local-storage isn't available in plain JS.

Comment: have you tried using AJAX? perhaps this is what you need

Comment: I could look into it.

Comment: I am not too familiar with AJAX, how could I use AJAX with node.js to push it to the front end where I can edit an html value?

Comment: https://mherman.org/blog/handling-ajax-calls-with-node-dot-js-and-express-scraping-craigslist/ there are so many resources you can find about AJAX and Nodejs